# use ints for prop.setProperty()

Tags: java, properties

i'm trying to do a configurations file from an array of objects, where the properties are taken from a range of getters. 
eg

```
    prop.setProperty("Name", bugs[0].getName());
    prop.setProperty("Species", bugs[0].getSpecies());
```

When i try, for example

```
prop.setProperty("Energy", bugs[0].getEnergy());
```

it says

> The method setProperty(String, String) in the type Properties is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, int)

How would I do method of `setProperty(String, Int)`?

EDIT*
Also, How do i write for an array of the objects, looping `bugs[i]` doesn't seem to work either.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bugs.length; i++) {
        prop.setProperty("Name", bugs[i].getName());
        prop.setProperty("Species", bugs[i].getSpecies());
        prop.setProperty("X", String.valueOf(bugs[i].getX()));
        prop.setProperty("Y", String.valueOf(bugs[i].getY()));
        prop.setProperty("Energy", String.valueOf(bugs[i].getEnergy()));
        prop.setProperty("Symbol", String.valueOf(bugs[i].getId()));
        }
        // save properties to project root folder
        prop.store(output, null);
```

How would i make it show the values for all the bugs, its only showing the last one?

Comment: It's not totally clear what you are asking. What is "prop" an instance of, i.e., what class? What are the methods of that class? It looks like the setProperty method only takes two strings as an argument and you are giving it a string and and integer. Are you asking how to convert an integer to a string?

Comment: I didn't got the second part of your question clearly "How do i write for an array of the objects".

Comment: Post code for your second statement `How do i write for an array of the objects, looping bugs[i] doesn't seem to work either` or put some light on that so we can help you to resolve it.

Comment: Added edit for second part

Answer (score 2):

`bugs[0].getEnergy()` is giving integer value to you and you are setting integer value insted of string that why exception came in your code.

Try

```
prop.setProperty("Energy", String.valueOf(bugs[0].getEnergy()));
```

For second part of Question :

> How do i write for an array of the objects, looping bugs[i] doesn't
>   seem to work either.

Your loop showing last value because your `key` of property is same, you are not changing the key assigning all values to same key so it is giving you last value.

Try something , It will create new keys

```
for (int i = 0; i < bugs.length; i++) {
    prop.setProperty("Name"+i, bugs[i].getName());
    prop.setProperty("Species"+i, bugs[i].getSpecies());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you can do this in two ways:

### First way:

**Overloading** the `setProperty();` metod. As it seems you decleared this method some where like this:

```
public void setProperty(String s1, String s2) {
// Doing some operations
}
```

Now, you can overload another method with the **same name**, but **different signature** to handle another kind of arguments (`String - int`), like this:

```
public void setProperty(String s1, int value) {
// Doing some operations suitable for this kind of method
}
```

### Second way:

You can also easily convert the value of given integer to the string, by `String.valueOf();` method, like this:

```
prop.setProperty("Energy", String.valueOf(bugs[0].getEnergy()));
```

## EDITED:

In the loop you entered here, you're overwriting the values of `prop` object properties every time you loop through `for`.

First time the `name` of `prop` will be the `bugs[0].getName()`. In the next time, the last value will be deleted and `bugs[1].getName()` replaces it.
So if you want to store all of `bugs` array properties, you need an array of `prop` like objects (I don't know whats the type of `prop` but I assume it's `Prop`). So you need to write something like this:

```
Prop[] props = new Prop[bugs.length];
```

And then set properties of it's elements.

Also if you want to store all of properties in one object, you have to change the given `key` to `setProperty(String, Int)` method (as the `String`). So you can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bugs.length; i++) {
    prop.setProperty("Name " + i, bugs[i].getName());
    prop.setProperty("Species " + i, bugs[i].getSpecies());
    // An so
}
prop.store(output, null);
```

Comment: What do you mean by parse integer? `Integer.parseInt` returns integer, while method `setProperty` expects String (but OP provides integer so compiler complains about it). You probably wanted to use `Integer.toString`, or to be null-safe `String.valueOf`.